# I can't find my removable disk K on windows vista

Tags: windows-vista

I can't find my removable disk K on windows vista. What should i do. Normally when I shut down my computer it shows up. I did it today and it just did not show up so please tell me what to do...........

Answer (score 0):

If you provide additional information, it might be easier to help you.

Since it's a removable disk, I'm going to assume it's a USB pluggable device, e.g. external hard drive, memory stick or something.

Why it would show up when you're shutting down I have no idea, or why you would want this.

First steps to troubleshoot this problem would be to try connecting device to another port (if applicable), reboot computer, check if device works on another system and so on. This can be the case of a failing device, port or limitation in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in disk management to see if the drive letter (drive letters on removable devices can change) is no longer there?  Or if it is showing up in there at all?